# Using Chinese brackets with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, xetex, cjk, xecjk

I would like to use Chinese brackets with `biblatex`. Is this possible? I could not figure out how from the manual. It should look like the second example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}


\usepackage[
    natbib=true,
    citestyle=authoryear-comp,
    maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=2,
    isbn=false,
    doi=false,
    url=false,
    eprint=false,
    backend=biber,
    indexing=cite,
    ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\bibliography{bibliography}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
  @misc{FSP2016a,
Author = {Antonio Fabregas and Tom Stroik and Michael Putnam},
Howpublished = {Ms.\ Penn State University},
Title = {Is Simplest Merge too simple?},
Year = {2016}}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

更多最近有关合并的构成的标记和大量的过度分析请看 \citet{FSP2016a}。

更多最近有关合并的构成的标记和大量的过度分析请看 Fabregas et al.（2016）。


\end{document}
```

Comment: All round parentheses ever produced by `biblatex` or only some?

Comment: No, `biblatex` produces normal ascii brackets.

Comment: With `bibtex`there was a command `\bibpunct` with which one could change the punctuation. No such thing seems to exist for `biblatex`.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear. Do you want all parentheses that `biblatex` inserts automatically to be CJK round brackets or do you want that to happen in only an assorted lot of specific situations? `biblatex` does not have a `\bibpunct` command, but it has similar capabilities.

Comment: Yes, I guess "everywhere" would be the expected occurance of Chinese brackets.

Comment: OK, theoretically this should be easy, but I'm having difficulties with the spaces at the moment (the reason why you had to write `Fabregas et al.（2016）。` without a space in `.（` and `）。`).

Comment: Yes, this is funny about Chinese. They basically do not have spaces. It is all one square for one character and the brackets have space built in.

Answer (score 5):

The command that `biblatex` ultimately uses to insert a left round bracket is `\bibleftparen` and that for a right round bracket `\bibrightparen`. You can modify these two commands to your liking. Unfortunately the CJK parentheses seem to bring their own space (that's why you wrote `Fabregas et al.（2016）。` without additional space), so we need to hack our way out of these spaces.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibleftparen}{\unspace\blx@postpunct（}
\renewcommand*{\bibrightparen}{\blx@postpunct）\unspace\midsentence}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! You rock! This also solves a problem with linebrakes after the bracket and before the dot, which I could not solve with `bibtex`.

Comment: I think the unspace should not be done when in the middle of a sentence: 的过度分析请看\citep{FSP2016a}更多最近有关合. Here, Chinese expects the space. For strange reasons the spacing seems to work on the left-hand side.

Comment: Ideally the command would eat up all following spaces but leave the space that belongs to the bracket and have the CJK mechanism decide whether the dot goes close to the bracket or whether the space is preserved since a normal Chinese character is following.

Comment: @StefanMüllern Sorry, that is the best I can do. I don't really know how the whole spacing business works, but there are chances that `biblatex` (like `hyperref`) interferes here (maybe it goes via kerning, that could be problematic https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/598). One of the xeCJK developers is active on this site, maybe he sees your question and can help you.

Comment: @StefanMüller In fact simple grouping such as `\begingroup Fabregas et al.（2016）\endgroup。` is already enough to destroy the correct spacing. Since `biblatex`'s `\cite` commands involve quite a bit of grouping I see no chance to preserve the automatic spacing.

Comment: @StefanMüller: I think one should use a normal space before/after a `\cite` command manually when necessary. It is the author's responsibility to handle spacing when mixing Chinese and English.  `xeCJK` is not that smart to handle all the spacing issues automatically. `luatexja` works better in these situations, but still not fully automatically.

Comment: @moewe In fact I'm not active on tex.sx for several years. I did not notice this question until Stefan send a mail to us.

Comment: @LeoLiu Oh, sorry. I had seen your answers here and there and assumed you were still active. All the more reason to send emails via the channels established in the documentation instead of hoping that bug reports are noticed on TeX.SX. I was hesitant to suggest to Stefan to mail you (or "the developers" in general) here though, since I don't really think this is a bug you can work-around. I assumed it is a result of the general approach. Anyway thanks for getting back here and describing the 'official position'.